# Prestashop - home featured products title translation

Tags: prestashop

I need to change the title of "home featured" module from `TitleA` to `TitleB`.
This title is missing in back office module translations and I also didn't find it via FTP.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to find this title in backoffice not in Installed Modules but in General Translations.

or if You dont use other languages in Your store

in **tab.tpl** file located in **themes/default-bootstrap/modules/homefeatured** You can edit it manualy

```
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#homefeatured" class="homefeatured">{l s='Popular' mod='homefeatured'}</a></li>
```

to

```
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#homefeatured" class="homefeatured">{l s='Your title' mod='homefeatured'}</a></li>
```